# I am trying to get notifications to for my app in flutter but whenever I import Flutter Push Notifications I get an error

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications

Whenever I put this in my dependencies and use it in a file
 flutter_local_notifications: ^0.7.1+3

Not sure if its version numbers that could be causing this

These are my other dependencies

dependencies:

flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: 0.2.5+1

# The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  cloud_firestore: 0.8.2+3
  shared_preferences: 0.5.3+1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: Try adding `multiDexEnabled true` in the app/build.gradle android > defaultConfig

Comment: Its already enabled

Comment: Seems like you preventing the AndroidX with those versions except for shared_preferences with should be 0.4.3       https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility#avoiding-androidx